# Being notified with key of sub-property changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue let you have watchers that monitor a given property (even nested):

```
// keypath
vm.$watch('a.b.c', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  // do something
})
```

However, given a vue instance like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    options: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      c: 3
    }
  },
})
```

Is there a way to watch `options` such that I'm notified when any child property is changed with the `key` as well as the `value`?

**Note:** *I'm looking to also obtain what key the changed value related to.*

Something that would respond back with something like: `function(key, value) {}`
Possibly even: `function(key, value, oldValue) {}`?

Comment: I think  your  way is to check if the key exists in your object.

Comment: But the key would always exist. When watching a nested object you always get the whole object in the callback - not just the subset that changed.

Comment: That's right I am curious to know the answer for your question so i've upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the keys and make a watcher for each that calls a method with the key and values.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      c: 3
    }
  },
  created() {
    for (const k of Object.keys(this.options)) {
      this.$watch(`options.${k}`, (newVal, oldVal) => this.optionWatcher(k, newVal, oldVal));
    }
  },
  methods: {
    optionWatcher(key, newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(`Updated ${key} from ${oldVal} to ${newVal}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="k in Object.keys(options)">{{k}}={{options[k]}}<button @click="++options[k]">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a sharm! Wish this was part of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

By default Vue will watch all properties you define in data, so when you change options.a, options.b and options.c Vue will notice. But if you set something like

```
options.d = 'foo'
```

Vue won't notice it. For vue to watch options.d, you need to use Vue.set: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: As @Amr-Aly mentioned, using the `deep` option let you monitor nested properties. But the docs only show how you get the old and new values - not which key they relate to.